# WordPress Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processPastedContent' of undefined

Tags: wordpress

I just realized that a "normal" paste into a WordPress article does not work anymore: I use wordpress 4.9.4 (on premise) and Chrome65. Anyone experiencing the same problems. Here the console output after hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php:652)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php:3)
    at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php:9)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php:3)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php:2)
    at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php:4)
/blog/wp-content/plugins/image-elevator/assets/admin/js/image-elevator.tinymce.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isClipboardActive' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.editor.getDoc.onpaste (/blog/wp-content/plugins/image-elevator/assets/admin/js/image-elevator.tinymce.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:31)
post.php:3315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processPastedContent' of undefined
    at Object.paste_preprocess (post.php:3315)
    at q.<anonymous> (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at b.e [as fire] (tinymce.min.js:6)
    at q.fire (tinymce.min.js:6)
    at Object.a [as firePastePreProcess] (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at e (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at Object.f [as process] (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at m (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at n (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
    at a (/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4607-20180123:1)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see it says something about "image-elevator". I checked my plugins and found the following plugin actived:
OnePress Image Elevator (Version 2.5.8) by OnePress
After deactivating the plugin past works again.